# how to center various width images while having a block of text flush right of each image?

Tags: html, css, scale, centering

I have an image gallery where I want the images horizontally centered on the page.  I want to have the image meta data, title, artist-name etc, positioned just to the right of that image.

First I tried floating the image and the meta_data side by side inside a containing div, but then the image is no longer centered according to the page because the overall containing div width is used for centering.  Also, I don't know the width of the containing div should be since I don't know the width of the image, it's dynamic.  I prefer not to set a hardcoded width on the div because I want to let the image scale down depending on the devise.

Then I tried using `display:table display:row display:cell`, where the image was in the left cell and the meta data was in the right cell.  The table would stretch to the width of the image, which was great.  I then put `position:relative` on the meta data table-cell and then `positive:absolute` the a div which contained the meta data off to the right.  This worked great in most browsers but didn't display correctly in FF.  I found that `table-cell` and `position:relative` didn't mix well... even if the `position:relative` was nested in a different element.

So then I tried putting both the image and meta data elements in a containing div that was `display:inline-block; positive:relative`.  Again this stretched around my content without extending all the way to the max width, the way a regular `display:block` does, which was great.  Again I positioned the meta data absolutely to the right.  It looks great in chrome, ff and safari... BUT, now my dynamic image scaling breaks.  I had size the image `max-width:100%` so that it will scale down for mobile devices.  But in FF this doesn't work.  I supposed the image can't get a read on what the width is on the inline-block?  I tried putting another div around the image that was `display:block` but that still doesn't work.

What is a good way of centering the images, yet have a piece of text positioned flush to its right, yet still have image respond to `max-width:100%` when scaled?

[Example](http://www.sketchfemme.com/popular) of what I have so far:

Answer (score 0):

In FF, adding `width: 100%` to the content container allows it to flex at smaller screen size; however, this causes it to break and the container to fill the whole width at larger screen sizes. Are you using media queries? If so, you could set the width proper once you drop below a specified screen width.